# Pointer difficulties... what's the difference between these snippets?

Tags: c, pointers

Hopefully this example will help out any one else having trouble wrapping their heads around pointers.

Please point me in the right direction here- I'm not sure why these two snippets of code behave differently. Option 1 works fine without any memory leaks, but option 2 loses reference to other trie nodes. Looking at them, however, I can't seem to pick out what makes them different.

Here's the code:

add_word adds a node to a trie data structure.
create_trie mallocs a new node and returns a pointer to that node

```
void add_word(trie_node **node, char *word, int i)
{
    // Option 1
    trie_node *new_node;

    if ((*node)->branches[(int) word[i]] == NULL) {
        (*node)->branches[(int) word[i]] = create_trie();

    }

    new_node = (*node)->branches[(int) word[i]];

    if (word[i + 1] == '\0') {
        new_node->end_of_word = 1;
    } else {
        i++;
        add_word(&new_node, word, i);
    }

    // Option 2
    trie_node *new_node = (*node)->branches[(int) word[i]];

    if (new_node == NULL) {
        new_node = create_trie();

    }

    if (word[i + 1] == '\0') {
        new_node->end_of_word = 1;
    } else {
        i++;
        add_word(&new_node, word, i);
    }

}
```

Comment: Clearly, the difference is that in Option 1, you assign the newly-created trie to `(*node)->branches[(int) word[i]]`, whereas in Option 2, you assign it only to `new_node`, which is a temporary variable, so you lose your reference to it. I don't really see how this will be useful to others.

Comment: `new_node = create_trie();` : `new_node` is overwritten with `create_trie();` and is no longer pointing to `(*node)->branches[(int) word[i]];
`.